# Compile embedded SQL C with rowset cursors on DB2/AIX64 11.1.4.6

Tags: compilation, db2, aix, rowset

My source code - C service routine using cursors with rowset positioning compiles on z/OS. We are porting everything to AIX using similar compiling procedures. Old db2 version we had on AIX didn't support rowset cursors but this new one should.

The compile procedure fails at the first line where it finds a struct definition for host variables using 2D arrays. This is a prerequisite for rowset cursors.

```
  char       SL_ISO2    ??(19??) ??(3??) ;
```

db2 prep line:

```
   db2 prep $PC_SYSIN bindfile USING $PC_DBRMLIB OUTPUT $PC_SYSTSIN $PC_PARAMS $BIND_PARAMS
```

And the output of the compiler procedure for this

```
   448   SQL0008N  The token "[" found in a host variable
         declaration is not valid.
```

Everything works on z/OS and all programs without rowsets compile on AIX. Compiler is XLC 13.1.3.4. AIX 7100-05-09-2136.
Some clues I found online suggest that I should try some db2 prep preprocessor option but so far no success.

Comment: Where in the Db2-LUW v11.1 documentation do you see support for embedded-SQL rowset cursors?   I can see that some CLI functions allow it, but not embedded-SQL.

Comment: I don't understand the process. I ran db2cli validate and it says that: The validation utility could not find the configuration file db2dsdriver.cfg. My admin says I don't need this. Thanks